# Quality of inputs in chess game databases?

Tags: database

```
[Event "FIDE Women's World Chess Championship"]
[Site "Sochi RUS"]
[Date "2015.03.17"]
[EventDate "2015.03.17"]
[Round "1.1"]
[Result "1/2-1/2"]
[White "Tatiana Kosintseva"]
[Black "Mary Ann Gomes"]
[ECO "B47"]
[WhiteElo "?"]
[BlackElo "?"]
[PlyCount "159"]
[FEN ""]

1. e4 c5 2. Nf3 e6 3. d4 cxd4 4. Nxd4 Nc6 5. Nc3 Qc7 6. Be2 a6
7. O-O Nf6 8. Be3 Be7 9. f4 d6 10. Qe1 Nxd4 11. Bxd4 O-O
12. Qg3 b5 13. a3 Bb7 14. Bd3 Rad8 15. Kh1 Nh5 16. Qh3 Nxf4
17. Rxf4 e5 18. Nd5 Bxd5 19. exd5 g6 20. Raf1 f5 21. Bxf5 gxf5
22. Rxf5 Rxf5 23. Rxf5 Rf8 24. Qg4+ Kh8 25. Bc3 Qc8 26. Rxf8+
Qxf8 27. Qf3 Qh6 28. h3 Qc1+ 29. Kh2 h6 30. Bb4 Bg5 31. Bxd6
Bf4+ 32. g3 Qxc2+ 33. Qg2 Bxg3+ 34. Kxg3 Qg6+ 35. Kf2 Qxd6
36. Ke2 Qc5 37. Qe4 Qc7 38. Kd2 Qd6 39. h4 Kg7 40. h5 Qf6
41. Qg4+ Kf8 42. Ke3 Ke7 43. Ke4 a5 44. Qg3 Kd7 45. Qxe5 Qh4+
46. Kd3 Qg4 47. Kc2 Qc4+ 48. Kd2 Qg4 49. Kc2 Qc4+ 50. Kd2 Qg4
51. d6 Qg2+ 52. Ke3 Qg1+ 53. Ke4 Qg2+ 54. Kd3 Qf1+ 55. Kd4
Qc4+ 56. Ke3 Qc1+ 57. Kd3 Qd1+ 58. Ke3 Qe1+ 59. Kd4 Qg1+
60. Ke4 Qg2+ 61. Kd3 Qf1+ 62. Kc2 Qc4+ 63. Kd2 Kc6 64. Qe8+
Kxd6 65. Qf8+ Ke5 66. Qxh6 Qd5+ 67. Kc1 Qc4+ 68. Kd1 Qf1+
69. Kd2 Qg2+ 70. Kd3 Qf1+ 71. Kc2 Qf5+ 72. Kc1 Qf1+ 73. Kc2
Qf5+ 74. Kc1 Qf1+ 75. Kd2 Qc4 76. Kd1 Qf1+ 77. Kd2 Qg2+
78. Kd3 Qf1+ 79. Kc2 Qc1+ 80. Kxc1 1/2-1/2
```

First of all, how can I avoid the automatical numbering installed here,
which is not useful for the purpose of entering games ?

I wonder about the quality of entering chess games in databases. The
most recent entry I found in chessgames.com was the one above, but not the only one.
In a game of the reykjavic open there was also a game where the last
move was absurd. It was a rook end game and the last move shown was
Rh8, which would simply give away the rook ( I do not remember the game).

Why do regularly appear such errors ? Are the games entered manually or
is there an electronic devise which produces such annyoing errors ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the answer is "both".

Usually (in lower leagues and opens) games are entered manually, which obviously can lead to all kind of errors. But top level games are recorded by electronic boards, which can lead to trouble if the players are moving too fast or are positioning the pieces imprecisely. And there is the constant annoyance of arbiters placing the king on the central squares to input the result, which is quite often interpreted as an actual game move by the electronic board.